# How to use RegularExpressions in this case?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to extract the string between 2nd and 3rd slashes of a path name. For example, I have the following path:

C:\Users\myUserName\OneDrive\Documents\myDocument\

How can we extract the name **myUserName** above as a string in C#? Is there a way to do it with RegularExpressions or any other way?

I tried to search but didn't find a clear eaxmple.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This sounds like an XY problem. If you want to get the username of the logged in user, there might be different ways to do that.

Comment: with regular expressions? best not, because a simple string-split will do the job much easier, faster, and more readable

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `string.Split`.

```
var dirName = @"C:\Users\myUserName\OneDrive\Documents\myDocument\";
var userName = dirName.Split('\\')[2];
Console.WriteLine(userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex:

`[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\([^\\]+)\\.*`

where the 1st group will be the "myUserName"

https://regex101.com/r/qyKIw9/1